# PWA register push notifications for Azure Notification Hub using JS only

Tags: azure, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a PWA and following the example for subscribing to push notifications as detailed in this Google Lab - [Adding Push Notifications to a Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/)

The example uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) but we already have an Azure Notification Hub

Am I able to register with ANH using the same approach (JS only) - would it be a case of sending an API call with a payload containing the hub name, connection string and registration id?

Comment: Did you manage to build your PWA and send notifications to users with the ANH? I'm interested in doing this for our client's website as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this documentation about [Tutorial: Push notifications to Chrome apps with Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-chrome-push-notifications-get-started). There a sample code there that can send an API call containing the hub name, connection string and registration id.

> **Note**: The sample uses CryptoJS v3.1.2. If you downloaded another
>   version of the library, make sure you properly substitute the version
>   in the src path.

Where [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) is a growing collection of standard and secure cryptographic algorithms implemented in 
**JavaScript** using best practices and patterns.

Comment: this answer is outdated, the link does not exist anymore